# mysql multiple insert query results top 13 values are fine rest (all same don't know from where)

Tags: mysql

The problem is when I use this query top 13 values are perfect then all of a sudden from the 14th row onwards the middle value (code) are all same for rest all of them and it is not even from the data I am providing.
Tried everything
changed table
changed type
on/off ai for "id"
on/off unique "code" when on it doesn't run
changed database

```
INSERT INTO employee(id, code, status) VALUES 
(  1,2020599896,1), (  2,2047604596,1), (  3,2052733439,1), (  4,2060586324,1), (  5,2074811361,1), 
(  6,2095521791,1), (  7,2101265532,1), (  8,2114874189,1), (  9,2120555236,1), ( 10,2129981821,1), 
( 11,2130132745,1), ( 12,2130996404,1), ( 13,2144032006,1), ( 14,2166524773,1), ( 15,2168033575,1), 
( 16,2169398647,1), ( 17,2177929854,1), ( 18,2180635290,1), ( 19,2181055332,1), ( 20,2181190386,1), 
( 21,2181990363,1), ( 22,2183599378,1), ( 23,2186523276,1), ( 24,2186971517,1), ( 25,2187287889,1), 
( 26,2188542563,1), ( 27,2192644744,1), ( 28,2200016307,1), ( 29,2203899683,1), ( 30,2204015321,1), 
( 31,2231842531,1), ( 32,2240206744,1), ( 33,2246983593,1), ( 34,2251943292,1), ( 35,2260530015,1), 
( 36,2261036459,1), ( 37,2261137729,1), ( 38,2261226209,1), ( 39,2262362656,1), ( 40,2264379567,1), 
( 41,2266443163,1), ( 42,2267071104,1), ( 43,2267845879,1), ( 44,2268804826,1), ( 45,2269686602,1), 
( 46,2271549012,1), ( 47,2274352216,1), ( 48,2275612709,1), ( 49,2275688477,1), ( 50,2281897955,1), 
( 51,2282102959,1), ( 52,2282577630,1), ( 53,2284298805,1), ( 54,2286729666,1), ( 55,2289188050,1), 
( 56,2289188761,1), ( 57,2291962435,1), ( 58,2294938036,1), ( 59,2295186387,1), ( 60,2296775907,1), 
( 61,2297579712,1), ( 62,2298314135,1), ( 63,2300054356,1), ( 64,2300295322,1), ( 65,2301689804,1), 
( 66,2303455873,1), ( 67,2306082021,1), ( 68,2306805264,1), ( 69,2307090205,1), ( 70,2307175063,1), 
( 71,2313041531,1), ( 72,2313641827,1), ( 73,2316020086,1), ( 74,2316450564,1), ( 75,2318799802,1), 
( 76,2319335952,1), ( 77,2319340002,1), ( 78,2319564684,1), ( 79,2319887416,1), ( 80,2325255939,1), 
( 81,2325446470,1), ( 82,2325718563,1), ( 83,2325864441,1), ( 84,2326829096,1), ( 85,2327372856,1), 
( 86,2327492340,1), ( 87,2328906363,1), ( 88,2330560299,1), ( 89,2331820254,1), ( 90,2331947198,1), 
( 91,2333132476,1), ( 92,2333565394,1), ( 93,2334225691,1), ( 94,2336068560,1), ( 95,2336668054,1), 
( 96,2336682717,1), ( 97,2336996455,1), ( 98,2337405845,1), ( 99,2337479535,1), (100,2337589051,1), 
(101,2338269604,1), (102,2339753721,1), (103,2340502943,1), (104,2341162507,1), (105,2341336309,1), 
(106,2341494199,1), (107,2341508527,1), (108,2342299043,1), (109,2342374788,1), (110,2342972037,1), 
(111,2343636128,1), (112,2344393323,1), (113,2344535113,1), (114,2345087437,1), (115,2345985515,1), 
(116,2346048735,1), (117,2346134915,1), (118,2346311018,1), (119,2349221560,1), (120,2349479416,1), 
(121,2352686915,1), (122,2353781483,1), (123,2356781845,1), (124,2356900080,1), (125,2357484928,1), 
(126,2357951595,1), (127,2363617313,1), (128,2364510996,1), (129,2366775175,1), (130,2367928476,1), 
(131,2374828925,1), (132,2176828420,1), (133,2198459626,1), (134,2325897920,1), (135,2371179793,1), 
(136,2371500972,1)
```

Comment: What is the data type of the faulty column? You appear to be exceeding the max integer value. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/integer-types.html

Comment: what data type is used in 'code' column

Comment: You will need to make `code` a `BIGINT` type, or at least give it an `UNSIGNED` attribute.  If it won't be treated numerically (making use of arithmetic, SUM() aggregates, etc), you may also wish to store it as a `VARCHAR()` type. The name `code` suggests it may be a value that wouldn't suffer from being stored as a character type.

Comment: int is the type 255 (i think i.e. is the max limit)

Comment: What have you tried to resolve the problem? Where are you stuck?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `code` is `INT` you are exceeding the limit.

```
+-----------+---------+----------------------+----------------------+
|   Type    | Storage |    Minimum Value     |    Maximum Value     |
+-----------+---------+----------------------+----------------------+
|           | (Bytes) | (Signed/Unsigned)    | (Signed/Unsigned)    |
| TINYINT   | 1       | -128                 | 127                  |
|           |         | 0                    | 255                  |
| SMALLINT  | 2       | -32768               | 32767                |
|           |         | 0                    | 65535                |
| MEDIUMINT | 3       | -8388608             | 8388607              |
|           |         | 0                    | 16777215             |
| INT       | 4       | -2147483648          | 2147483647           |
|           |         | 0                    | 4294967295           |
| BIGINT    | 8       | -9223372036854775808 | 9223372036854775807  |
|           |         | 0                    | 18446744073709551615 |
+-----------+---------+----------------------+----------------------+
```

Resource:https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/integer-types.html

So, all you have to do is change the `code` column data type to `BIGINT`

Answer (score 0):

Change the type of column, you are with INT type and reaches the limit, change it to BIG INT
Take a look here 
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/integer-types.html